# Determining convergence or Divergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{3n}{3n+1})^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{3n}{3n+1}\right)^n$$
A cauchy root test will not work since $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{(\frac{3n}{3n+1})^n} = 1$. However, by inspection, as $n \to \infty$ the sum reduces to:

$$\sim^{\infty} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} 1$$ which diverges. Hence, can I conclude from this that the original series diverges?

Comment: How do you conclude it behaves as $1$?

Comment: As $n \to \infty $the inner fraction $\frac{3n}{3n+1} \to 1$. The power $1^n$ will simply reduce to 1. Is this correct>

Comment: @RedekMartinez No, $1^\infty$ is an indeterminate, in this particualr case it converges to $\frac1{e^{1/3}}$ if the exponent was $n^2$ instead of $n$ it would converge to $0$ instead.

Comment: So then an evaluation of the limit of $a_n$ is the most direct way of solving. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_n=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{3n}{3n+1}\right)^n = \mathrm{e}^{\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}n\ln\left(\dfrac{3n}{3n+1}\right)} =\mathrm{e}^T.$ Where $T = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{\ln\dfrac{3n}{3n+1}}{\dfrac{1}{n}}= \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{-3n^2(3n+1)}{3n(3n+1)^2}=-\dfrac{1}{3}.$ Thus $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_n = \mathrm{e}^{-\dfrac{1}{3}} \ne 0.$ So we can conclude that the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{3n}{3n+1})^n 
$ is divergence.

Comment: Note that for a series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ to converge, the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n$ has to be zero.

Comment: I believe that if one can use L'Hopital's rule for sequences then he/she can answer the original question easily anyway.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:**

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{3n}{3n+1}\right)^n\ne 0$$

Comment: So if the limit of the nth term does not reach zero, then the series will be constantly increasing? Is this a formal test? Intuitively it makes sense.

Comment: Yes.  For a series to converge, the general terms must approach $0$.

Comment: Although your idea was helpful and correct, aDmaL more clearly showed that the limit is not 0 by evaluating, which made his answer a bit better. Clearly evaluating was recommended as an appropriate step by other contributors. If I could accept both I would, since all of the answers provided are correct.... sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
\left( {\frac{{3n}}{{3n + 1}}} \right)^n  = \frac{1}{{\left( {1 + \frac{1}{{3n}}} \right)^n }} = \frac{1}{{\sqrt[3]{{\left( {1 + \frac{1}{{3n}}} \right)^{3n} }}}} \ge \frac{1}{{e^{1/3} }}.
$$